# How to use 1 field in 2 columns when merging tables

Tags: sql

I need help reusing 1 column in table 1 in 2 columns of the output. Please see attached screenshot for the goal. Thanks in advance for the help

My attempt:

```
SELECT
    t2.ID,
    t1.name AS case_owner,
    t1.name AS case_created_by
FROM 
    t2
JOIN
    t1 ON t2.case_owner = t1.id
JOIN
    t1 ON t2.case_created_by = t1.id
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can alias one of the t1 joins, like: "join t1 as t1_created_by on ...

```
Select
t2.ID,
t1_owner.name as case_owner,
t1_creator.name as case_created_by
FROM t2
join t1 t1_owner on t2.case_owner= t1_owner.id
join t1 t1_creator on t2.case_created_by= t1_creator.id
```

Comment: thanks for prompt assistance, did not know you could also have alias for tables,

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **unique aliases** for the table joined twice:

```
SELECT
    t2.ID,
    TOwner.name AS case_owner,
    TCreator.name AS case_created_by
FROM 
    t2
JOIN
    t1 AS TOwner ON t2.case_owner = TOwner.id
JOIN
    t1 AS TCreator ON t2.case_created_by = TCreator.id
```

Comment: thanks for prompt assistance, did not know you could also have alias for tables,